# How to extract original prices using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, loops, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn BeatifulSoup but currently having trouble with extracting prices (especially if there's a discount / strike through). I am only interested when there's a discount (itemprop = "offers") and for this exercise, I just want to extract the original price.

Full HTML can be obtain by inspecting this page:
https://www.patagonia.ca/shop/mens-hard-shell-jackets-vests

Highlighted desired target in the HTML below:

[image: targeted price]

I have tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

page = requests.get("https://www.patagonia.ca/shop/mens-hard-shell-jackets-vests", verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

div_price = []

for section_tag in soup.find_all('div', class_='product-tile__meta-primary'):
    for div_prices in section_tag.find_all('div', class_='price'):
        if div_prices.get('itemprop') == 'offers':
            for x in div_prices.find_all('span', {'class':'strike-through list'}):        
                for y in x.find_all('span', class_='value'):
                    div_price.append(y.get('content'))
        else:
            continue
```

The above code gives me the desired prices - I only want the original price ($499) and **not** the discounted price ($349.30) - however it gets repeated multiple times :(

> ['499.00',  '435.00',  '879.00',  '999.00',  '799.00',  '499.00', 
>   '435.00',  '879.00',  '999.00',  '799.00',  '499.00',  '435.00', 
>   '879.00',  '999.00',  '799.00',  '499.00',  '435.00',  '879.00', 
>   '999.00', . . .

Also I'm not proud with the nested loops I'm hoping the community can help to fix these two bugs (feels like I'm missing something simple here but I just can't get my head around it):

1. If there's a better way without using all the loops I'm all ears
2. Is there a better way to extract the required info other than keep using find_all (still within BeautifulSoup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the price directly by the attr `itemprop` on the targeted span.
For the jacket where there are 2 prices, I use `find` method so it take only the first found span, so the price without discount

You can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

page = requests.get("https://www.patagonia.ca/shop/mens-hard-shell-jackets-vests")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

div_price = []
# Loop on elements
for jacket in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'product-tile__content'}):
    span_price = jacket.find('span', {'itemprop': 'price'})
    if span_price:
        div_price.append(span_price.get('content'))
print(div_price)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
['189', '189', '189', '189', '189', '189', '189', '189', '189', '189', '435', '499.00', '435.00', '189', '879.00', '249', '499', '999.00', '799.00', '249', '749', '499', '159', '879', '685', '499', '315', '625', '169', '625', '475', '435', '599', '375', '315', '625', '499', '315']
```

Comment: exactly what I need! thanks @Maaz and this is useful framework too since the website actually have ranged price as well (other than discounted price)

Answer (score 1):

```
for price in soup.select('.price'):

    if price.select('.strike-through.list'):
        print(price.select('.strike-through.list'))
    else:
        print(price.select('.sales'))
```

This code should get you the price of strike-through list class if it is available, else it will get the original 'sales' class rate.

The span logic should work based on your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the select function? how does it know which class to traverse to?

Comment: select is a CSS selector in bs4, refer https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.patagonia.ca/shop/mens-hard-shell-jackets-vests", verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

div_price = []
for price in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'strike-through list'}):
    div_price.append(str(price.text).strip()[3:])

print(div_price)
```

Output:

```
['499', '435', '879', '999', '799']
```